# C language wrong output...pascal triangle using 2d arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, output, pascals-triangle

So this is my code for printing pascal triangle using 2d arrays but its not giving me the desired output and I cannot determine what's wrong with the logic/code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num, rows, col, k;
    printf("Enter the number of rows of pascal triangle you want:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    long a[100][100];

    for (rows = 0; rows < num; rows++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < (num - rows - 1); col++)
            printf(" ");

        for (k = 0; k <= rows; k++)
        {
            if (k == 0 || k == rows)
            {
                a[rows][k] = 1;
                printf("%ld", a[rows][k]);
            }
            else
                a[rows][k] = (a[rows - 1][k - 1]) + (a[rows - 1][k]);
                printf("%ld", a[rows][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What value of `num` was used?  What output was expected?

Comment: Woops meant to make my answer a comment, to request ouput.

Comment: @Bwebb At least that "mistake" got you beyond 200 ;)

Comment: @Swordfish ill still fix this guys homework since that answer doesn't really count :p

Comment: i used 5 for the value of num

Comment: output i expected was a standard pascal triangle....not currently able to update the post with an added of the output for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have curly braces around the statements after the `else`, so it looks like you'll double-`printf()` when the condition of the `if`-statement is true.

I copied the source into codechef.com/ide and changed the io for num to be just assigned to 6 which produced the following output:

```
Enter the number of rows of pascal triangle you want:     
     11
    1111
   11211
  113311
 1146411
1151010511
```

It looks like your close, but you want 1, 11, 121, 1331 etc right?

Wraping the else case produced the following output:

```
 if (k == 0 || k == rows)

   {
        a[rows][k] = 1;
        printf("(%ld)", a[rows][k]);
    }

    else{// START OF BLOCK HERE
        a[rows][k] = (a[rows - 1][k - 1]) + (a[rows - 1][k]);
        printf("(%ld)", a[rows][k]);
    }//END OF BLOCK HERE, NOTE THAT IT INCLUDES THE PRINT IN THE ELSE CASE NOW

OUTPUT:
    Enter the number of rows of pascal triangle you want:
         (1)
        (1)(1)
       (1)(2)(1)
      (1)(3)(3)(1)
     (1)(4)(6)(4)(1)
    (1)(5)(10)(10)(5)(1)
```

But i added () to make it clearer to me.  I also added a "/n" to the end of the first printf that asks for the value of num, so that the first line is on a new line.

```
printf("Enter the number of rows of pascal triangle you want:\n");
```

Comment: @AnasAziz It looks good to me, what output are you getting wrong with the curly braces?  When you say something doesnt produce what you expected you should really make clear what it is doing and what you are expecting when you ask questions on here, it makes it much easier to answer that way.

Comment: @AnasAziz Ill keep commenting until you get the answer you're looking for, just please make sure to mark a comment as accepted when it answers the question you ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without using any arrays:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int num_digits(int number)
{
    int digits = 0;
    while (number) {
        number /= 10;
        ++digits;
    }
    return digits;
}

unsigned max_pascal_value(int row)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int num = row, denom = 1; num > denom; --num, ++denom)
        result = (int)(result * (double)num / denom );  
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number of rows of pascals triangle you want: ");
    int rows;
    if (scanf("%d", &rows) != 1) {
        fputs("Input error. Expected an integer :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int max_digits = num_digits(max_pascal_value(rows));
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; ++i) {
        for (int k = 0; k < (rows - i) * max_digits / 2; ++k)
            putchar(' ');

        int previous = 1;
        printf("%*i ", max_digits, previous);

        for (int num = i, denom = 1; num; --num, ++denom) {
            previous = (int)(previous * (double)num / denom );
            printf("%*i ", max_digits, previous);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Enter the number of rows of pascals triangle you want: 15
                                  1
                                1    1
                              1    2    1
                            1    3    3    1
                          1    4    6    4    1
                        1    5   10   10    5    1
                      1    6   15   20   15    6    1
                    1    7   21   35   35   21    7    1
                  1    8   28   56   70   56   28    8    1
                1    9   36   84  126  126   84   36    9    1
              1   10   45  120  210  252  210  120   45   10    1
            1   11   55  165  330  462  462  330  165   55   11    1
          1   12   66  220  495  792  924  792  495  220   66   12    1
        1   13   78  286  715 1287 1716 1716 1287  715  286   78   13    1
      1   14   91  364 1001 2002 3003 3432 3003 2002 1001  364   91   14    1
    1   15  105  455 1365 3003 5005 6435 6435 5005 3003 1365  455  105   15    1
```

Comment: If anyone has an idea about how to get the spacing right, comment away ;)

Comment: I upvoted it because of the spacing :)  Whats the printf("%*i" doing with two params though?  i thought it would multiply them but when i tested it it just printed the second param.

Comment: @Bwebb The first parameter `max_digits` is for the `*` and specifies the with of the field to print.

Comment: I am not familiar with * as a printf format specifier and i cant seem to find any info on it, can you link me something to read further.  I thought printf was a va_list and each param needed a % or else it would just get popped on the stack and do nothing (best case scenario)

Comment: @Bwebb https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf - read the description of parameter `format`. 2nd "(optional)" after "introductory % character".

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Ive only used something like printf("0x%02x ", uchar_value); for formatting.  Glad to learn something new.